# Map of generics of varying types

Tags: generics, rust

I'm trying to implement derived reactive stores, similar to [Svelte's derived stores](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/derived-stores). I am having trouble with generics; namely, that I can keep various pointers to a Store's upstream parent Stores (which may be different types) in the Store's properties as a HashMap using untyped traits (`HashMap<String, Box<dyn StoreFunctionality>>`). Unfortunately, I can't get the Store's value from the `StoreFunctionality` trait without typing it (`StoreFunctionality<T>`), which then means I am unable to put Stores of various types into the HashMap.

Each store:

- Can be of any type
- Can be updated via an initialization function when their parent's value changes
- Parent stores may not be the same type as child stores

The code I am trying:

```
/***
 * MAIN FUNCTION -- trying to initialize a store, initialize a second store, and then ensure that store 2's value updates when store1 updates
 */
 fn main() {
    let mut store1 = Store::<i32>::new(32, None, None);
    let value = store1.get();
    println!("store1 value 1: {:?}", value);

    let store2 = Store::<i32>::new(
        0,
        //Initialization function that updates store2's value based on store1's value
        Some(|store: Box<dyn StoreFunctionality>| {
            let d = store.get_upstream();
            let store1_value = match d.get("store1") {
                Some(store1) => {
                    //ERROR HERE - StoreFunctionality trait does not implement .get()
                    //Moving get into StoreFunctionality would require StoreFunctionality to have a generic type
                    //which defeats the purpose of having StoreFunctionality (to abstract the Store type)
                    *store1.get()
                },
                None => 0,
            };
            store1_value * 2
        }),
        //CUT FOR BREVITY - hashmap of upstream stoers set here
    );
    let value2 = store2.get();
    println!("store2 value: {:?}", value2);

    store1.update(10);
    println!(
        "store1 value 2: {:?}; store2 value 2: {:?}",
        store1.get(),
        store2.get()
    );
}
```

[Full playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d13376d03224e10dda90d414394d41c1)

The expected output of this code would be:

```
store1 value 1: 32
store2 value: 64
store 1 value 2: 10; store 2 value 2: 20
```

Here is a minimal look at the Store struct and implementations (this part of the code is error-free, according to rust_analyzer, but I'm sure there are better ways to do this):

```
pub trait StoreFunctionality {
    fn initialize_from_upstream_origins(&mut self);
    fn add_downstream(&mut self, key: String, store: Box<dyn StoreFunctionality>);
    fn get_upstream(&self) -> &HashMap<String, Box<dyn StoreFunctionality>>;
    fn report_downstream(&self);
}

pub struct Store<T> {
    //State
    value: T,
    pub initializer: Option<fn(&Self) -> T>,
    subscriptions: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&T) -> ()>>,

    //Derivation
    upstream_stores: HashMap<String, Box<dyn StoreFunctionality>>,
    downstream_stores: HashMap<String, Box<dyn StoreFunctionality>>,
}

impl<T> Store<T> {
    pub fn new(...) {
        //CUT FOR BREVITY, but may be of importance? See playground link.
    }

    pub fn get(&self) -> &T {
        &self.value
    }

    pub fn update(&mut self, new_value: T) {
        self.value = new_value;
        self.report_downstream();
    }
}
```

I should note: I'm new to Rust, but I tend to learn best by getting in over my head and digging my way out. Please pardon any blatantly bad form--I'm all ears if there are ways to improve what I have here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're running into here is that you've erased the type of the upstream and downstream stores using `dyn` but then you need to know the type of the value those stores hold.  This constraint in particular is problematic:

> Parent stores may not be the same type as child stores

This creates the problem you're facing, where you want the parent and child stores to be able to hold any kind of value, but then `store1_value * 2` implies that you need the value to support multiplication with an integer operand.

One way to handle this would be to introduce another trait that you require store values implement.  In this simple case, we can contrive one:

```
trait StoreValue {
    fn as_i32(&self) -> Option<i32>;
}
```

So at the bare minimum, a store value needs to *possibly* support conversion to `i32`.  We can implement it on `i32` trivially:

```
impl StoreValue for i32 {
    fn as_i32(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        Some(*self)
    }
}
```

For types that don't have an `i32` representation, we can just return `None`:

```
impl<T> StoreValue for Vec<T> {
    fn as_i32(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        None
    }
}
```

And still others might have an `i32` representation *sometimes:*

```
impl StoreValue for String {
    fn as_i32(&self) -> Option<i32> {
        self.parse().ok()
    }
}
```

Now it's just a matter of sprinkling in some `T: StoreValue` bounds, such as:

- ```
  impl<T: StoreValue> Store<T> {
  ```
- ```
  impl<T: StoreValue> StoreFunctionality for Store<T> {
  ```

Finally, we need to provide the missing `get` method on `StoreFunctionality`.  Since we've introduced the requirement that values must implement `StoreValue`, we can add a suitably-type-erased function to the trait:

```
fn get(&self) -> &dyn StoreValue;
```

And add it to the implementation of `StoreFunctionality` on `Store<T>`:

```
fn get(&self) -> &dyn StoreValue {
    &self.value
}
```

Easy enough.  Now your closure can be modified to make use of all of these changes by calling `.get().as_i32()` on the obtained store reference:

```
Some(|store: Box<dyn StoreFunctionality>| {
    let d = store.get_upstream();
    let store1_value = d.get("store1")
        .and_then(|s1| s1.get().as_i32())
        .unwrap_or(0);
    store1_value * 2
}),
```

This code will set `store1_value` to 0 either if `d` doesn't have a "store1" store, *or* if that store's value returns `None` from `StoreValue::as_i32()`.

So the final question for you to figure out is what `StoreValue` should look like.  You will need to define a set of operations common to all store values such that upstream and downstream stores can meaningfully operate on each others' values without actually knowing the concrete types of those values.

Alternatively, you can have `StoreFunctionality::get()` return `&dyn Any` but then you have to explicitly downcast to a concrete type, which is both fragile, verbose, and anti-polymorphic, but has the advantage of potentially less clutter in the `StoreValue` trait.

Which approach you take would depend heavily on what you intend to use this code for.

(Indeed, nothing prevents you from doing both -- that is, have `get()` return `&dyn StoreValue` and add a `get_any()` method that returns `&dyn Any`, or just add a method to `StoreValue` that casts the value as `&dyn Any`.)

---

Making these changes, there are still some remaining issues, one around the type of `Store::initializer`, which you declare to be `fn(&Self)` but the closure you pass to `Store::new` takes a `Box`.  Presumably you can just remove the argument type of `Box` from the closure altogether and the compiler should correctly infer it to be `&Store<T>`.

There's a few other minor issues that should be fairly straightforward to resolve as well.  (One the compiler even tells you how to fix.)

Comment: Thanks for this thorough look and level of detail. This patches several holes in my understanding and gives me some direction. Than you so much!